# Install Mobizen share android screen on PC

Tags: 14.04, android, sharing

How can Install `Mobizen` on ubuntu? I wanna share an `android screen` to `PC` . I using Mobizen but It just supports window, so I try to set up by `wine` but it not working.  plz, help me. Thanks?

Comment: There appear to be alternatives to Mobizen that work under Ubuntu

Answer (score -1):

I'm a new Ubuntu user and I'm trying to install `mobizen` with `wine`.

After the setup it does not start from [the desktop icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DQHM.png).

Thank you for the help, experts.

Comment: Si prega di inviare in inglese, questo è un forum internazionale

Comment: Ciao cgr05, ho tradotto in inglese e sintetizzato la tua domanda perchè sei un nuovo utente. Questo Q&A (putroppo) usa solo la lingua inglese ed i contenuti in altre lingue vengono cancellati. La prossima volta potresti avere meno fortuna. :-)
In ogni caso, ti diranno che questa domanda non è strettamente inerente ad Ubuntu, ma riguarda Wine. Attendi una risposta qui o rivolgiti al [forum](https://forum.winehq.org/) di Wine. Buona continuazione.